# Javascript: How to use object literals instead of if and switch statements for expression-based conditions?

Tags: javascript, object, control-flow

In javascript, I want to at least consider using a nested object literal tree for my control flow instead of if statements, switch statements, etc.

Below is an example of a function using if statements turned into a function using object literals to accomplish the same functionality.

```js
// if & else if
function getDrink (type) {
  if (type === 'coke') {
    type = 'Coke';
  } else if (type === 'pepsi') {
    type = 'Pepsi';
  } else if (type === 'mountain dew') {
    type = 'Mountain Dew';
  } else {
    // acts as our "default"
    type = 'Unknown drink!';
  }
  return type;
}

// object literal
function getDrink (type) {
  var drinks = {
    'coke': function () {
      return 'Coke';
    },
    'pepsi': function () {
      return 'Pepsi';
    },
    'Mountain Dew': function () {
      return 'Mountain dew';
    },
    'default': function () {
      return 'Unknown drink!';
    }
  };
  return (drinks[type] || drinks['default'])();
}
```

This works when testing for a simple value, but how could I turn the following switch statement into an object literal control structure?

```js
switch (true) {
  case (amount >= 7500 && amount < 10000):
    //code
    break;
  case (amount >= 10000 && amount < 15000):
    //code
    break;

  //etc...
```

Comment: You can't have an expression as an object key and I don't see anything wrong with a case or ifs for conditions? Also if your example is as simple as you've demonstrated you don't need to assign a function for every key, a value string would do.

Comment: Object keys can be expressions http://xahlee.info/js/js_object_literal_expression.html

Comment: Of course you can do your own computation on a string but it's totally overkill and slower to do so for a stylistic opinion

Comment: The goal is to make it look similar to this fiddle, but can't get it working.
It's much easier to read. My app does not care about speed.
https://jsfiddle.net/9txnegvh/11/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9txnegvh/14/ works

Comment: is there any way by which we can convert something like this to object literal, where a multiple cases in switch returns one value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use the simple way**

```
    const handlerPayment = () => { };
    const handlerFailure = () => { };
    const handlerPending = () => { };

    // Switch 
    switch (status) {
        case 'success':
            return handlerPayment();

        case 'failed':
            return handlerFailure();

        case 'pending':
            return handlerPending();
    
        default:
            throw Error('Status not recognize');
    }


    // Object
    const Handlers = {
        success: handlerPayment,
        failed: handlerFailure,
        pending: handlerPending,
    }
    
    const handler = Handlers[status];
    
    if (!handler) throw Error('Status not recognize');
    
    return handler();
```

Answer (score 3):

A small helper usong Array.find might be useful:

```
 const firstCase = (...cases) => value => cases.find(c=> c[0](value))[1];
```

Which is usable as:

```
const dayTime = firstCase(
  [t =>  t < 5, "night"],
  [t => t < 12, "morning"],
  [t => t < 18, "evening"],
  [true, "night"]
);

console.log(dayTime(10)); // morning
```

That also works with functions:

```
const greetAtTime = firstCase(
  [t => t < 10, name => `Good morning ${name}!`],
  [t => t > 18, name => `Good evening ${name}!`],
  [true, name => `Hello ${name}!`]
);

console.log(greetAtTime(12)("Jack"));
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it like this but it doesn't work, to avoid the function syntax if possible:
https://jsfiddle.net/9txnegvh/11/

Answer (score -1):

This appears to work

```js
const getValue = (value) => ({
  [value == 1]: 'Value is 1',
  [value > 1]: 'Value is greater than 1',
  [value < 1]: 'Value is less than 1',
})[true]

console.log(getValue(2));
console.log(getValue(-1)); 
console.log(getValue(-1+2)); // expect 'Value is 1'
```

Comment: This doesnt have the same behaviour as a `switch`. It will take the last case that is true, not the first one.