# Why does my if / else if statement work but my switch case doesn't?

Tags: javascript

So I have run into this problem which has been driving me nuts for the past couple of hours.

I have a conditional statement:

```
if (count == '0') {
  var variable = '0%'
  document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = variable
}
else if (count == '1') {
  var variable = '5%'
  document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = variable
}
else if (count == '2') {
  var variable = '10%'
  document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = variable
}
```

and it's working fine. The only problem is, I have 20 values so instead of writing the same `if/else if` for 20 values I decided to make a `switch` case:

```
switch (count) {
  case '0':
    var variable = '0 %'
    document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = variable
    break;
  case '1':
    var variable = '5 %'
    document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = variable
    break;
}
```

For some reason its not working, I really don't understand what's wrong.

TLDR: My `if/else if` is working fine but my `switch` case isn't and I can't figure out why not.

Comment: You are using the wrong type of quotes

Comment: `‘` that quote character is strange. I don't think JS allows it.

Comment: Why not just use `...innerHTML = \`${count * 5}%\``?

Comment: Switch uses `===` so your `count == '2'` is not same as `case 2`

Comment: Are you passing a string or an int into the switch statement.  1 !== '1'

Comment: @CodeManiac Good eye. That's most likely the problem (`2 == '2'`, but `2 !== '2'`)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Changed them, still not working.

Comment: Consider this alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817227/javascript-how-to-use-object-literals-instead-of-if-and-switch-statements-for-e

Comment: @jorton: people look ready to close this question, because they think it's a typographical error.  It looks more likely to be a question of  `1 == '1'`, but `1 !== '1'`.  Have you tried what Ardesco, p.s.w.g, and poniraq have suggested?

Comment: Note that you have multiple problems: invalid characters, redeclaring vars (neither if blocks nor case statements make a new scope for vars), use of loose-equality if your if/elses, no default handling in *either* example, etc. etc.

Comment: Looks like it got locked before I could answer, I'm going to suggest tweaking to use `switch(parseInt(count))` and than remove the quote marks from each case entry e.g. `case 1:`.  You also need to replace ` with '

Comment: I copied your code to my own html file and executed it. It worked fine.

Comment: @ScottSauyet one could make the argument that the missing `=` *is* a typographical error. This could also be closed for being unclear or not reproducible.

Comment: I think this needs more detail on `"still not working"`, as according to the OP the problem persists despite correcting the typographical error

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: did you try supplying a number to each, or only a string?  I think a number would give different behavior.

Comment: I did a string, didn't think of the number/string comparison.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/onm6q7ja/ shows the problem, I think, and it's not a typographical error, this should be reopened or marked as a duplicate

Comment: Sorry for yet another comment, but the updated fiddle shows the problem better, with the same check as the `switch` being performed with `if`s https://jsfiddle.net/dvzskw1c/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be type-conversion issue.

With "if" approach you're using type-converting comparison operator (==), so `0 == '0'` yields `true`.
Switch, on the other hand, uses strict comparison operator.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

> Strict Comparison
>
> Switch cases use strict comparison (===).
>
> The values must be of the same type to match.
>
> A strict comparison can only be true if the operands are of the same type.

Comment: I see that `let count = 0` doesn't work in a switch but `let count ='0'` does work. Never thought of that good find!

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you have weird quote characters in your switch:

[image]

The switch version looks like it is using "smart quotes" which are slanted depending on whether they are opening or closing. Many rich text editors convert regular quotes to smart quotes automatically, so if you wrote the code in a rich text originally, or copied and pasted it via Slack or something, that might explain where those characters came from.

Easy fix, though, just change them to regular quote characters as you have in your if statements.

Comment: Whenever I've seen this issue, it's usually because the code has been copy-pasted into a word processor (e.g. Word). IDE's will usually complain pretty loudly about this, or even automagically convert them back to 'simple' single-quotes. In other words, this is most likely due to the way OP was preparing the question for StackOverflow, rather than being an actual problem in the code.

Comment: Oh, yeah, OK, that just looked like the most obvious immediate problem, the type coercion thing makes sense after that.